# What is the proper way to set and update the contents of a field on a node in Drupal 7?

Tags: api, drupal, field, default-value, drupal-7

I've written a Drupal 7 module that creates a custom node type. I've added a number_integer field to the node, to act as a counter. How do I set the counter field to default to zero, when a node gets created?

Next, while processing the node, I need to increase the value of the counter by one and save the new value. Do I do that by altering the $node object and then calling node_save? Or is there a better way, using the Field API or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still would not really dare to save back a node just like that. I would still use

```
  $form_state = array('values' => array());
  drupal_form_submit('story_node_form', $form_state, $node);
```

much like we did in Drupal 6 (just with slightly different syntax).

Comment: The counter field isn't intended to be editable by the user, so it's not on a form anywhere. How would you handle that kind of field? In case it helps, I'm working on upgrading a module I wrote under Drupal 6, called Drubnub. The counter is a field I call "uses" that shows how many times a "command" gets used: https://drupal.org/project/drubnub

Comment: I'm also curious why you "would not dare" do it that way. What's "wrong" with doing it that way?

Comment: I talked to catch and he says that node_save() should work. My problem is that any module can do a number of things during a form submit but then again catch says that any module functionality breaking node_save should be considered a bug.